# Pandas Apply Function returns numpy.nan instead of None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My DataFrame has Null values and I would like to replace them with None to send them to Database. If I use apply function None gets written as Numpy.nan in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2, 4, 5, np.nan], columns = ['a'])
df.a.apply(lambda x: x if x==x else None)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

If I run below function it writes None in Dataframe.

```
df.a.apply(lambda x: None)
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
Name: a, dtype: object
```

This might be because of the column datatype is float and not Object. Any workaround for that? Thank you.

Comment: *send them to database*, maybe you should checkout `df.to_sql()`.

Comment: Although I agree with @QuangHoang, if you insist you can use `df = df.mask(df.isna(), None)`.

Comment: You could always make the dtype object before apply. `df.a.astype(object).apply(lambda x: x if x == x else None, convert_dtype=False)`